# Length of string in Jinja/Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, string-length

Jinja unfortunately does not support executing arbitrary Python code, such as

```
{% if len(some_var)>1 %} ... {% endif %}
```

My current workaround is to use the deprecated, ugly, double-underscore method:

```
{% if some_var.__len__()>1 %} ... {% endif %}
```

Although this works, I'm afraid that some future implementation of strings might break this code. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Note that despite not being the right solution here (use `|length` as indicated to you in the answers), `__len__` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use the [`length` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#length):

```
{% if some_var|length > 1 %}
```